# why viewWillAppear is not getting called?

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I have 2 nibs, when i am loading one view from the other, the viewWillAppear method of the nib which i am trying to load should get called as far as i know(both view did load and view will appear, view did load will be called only once when nib is loading but view will apper should get called whenever view is getting loaded).
But in my project viewWillAppear is not getting called even for once also.
what would be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code? The only thing I can think off the top of my head is the view outlet isn't set in IB...hard to tell though without code :)